# How to keep special characters in template variables on the commandline with pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to set a template variable with a string containing an umlaut. The body content is converted correctly, but the variable looses its special characters.

If I have a simple template `var-template.md`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
$for(navi)$<button name="navi" value="$navi$">$navi$</button>$endfor$
    </div>
    <div>
      $body$
    </div>
</html>
```

and try to convert with variables set:

```
echo Hällo Wörld | pandoc -w html --template=var-template -V navi="Übung 1" -V title="Laß das döch"
```

it outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>La� das d�ch</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <button name="navi" value="�bung 1">�bung 1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Hällo Wörld</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

So the body text is converted correctly, but the variables are not.
Is this a bug or a mistake?

I am on `ubuntu 12.04` with `pandoc 1.9.1` ... do I have to manually update from the repository-version to a newer on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this with the latest pandoc release, and it worked fine, so you may just need to upgrade.  You should also make sure that your locale is UTF-8.

Comment: You are right. I updated to pandoc 1.12.3.3 via cabal install and now it works as expected :) What a great tool!